# Name of the class of graphs obtained by deleting $\mathcal{Q}_d$ from $\mathcal{Q}_n$

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal{Q}_n$ denote the $n$-cube graph. I would like to know if there is a name for the class of graphs obtained by deleting a ${\bf single}$ arbitrary copy of $\mathcal{Q}_d$ from $\mathcal{Q}_n$, where $1 \leq d < n$. For example, when $d = 1$, this would involve removing two vertices that are connected by an edge, when $d = 2$, this would involve removing a square (i.e $4$ vertices of $\mathcal{Q}_2$) from $Q_n$, and so forth. Do these types of graphs have a name/have been studied previously?

Edit: I know that they are partial cubes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_cube - i.e an isometric subgraph of the hypercube, but I suspect something more specific can be said.

Comment: I may have an application for them with regards to vertex-disjoint path covers.

Answer (score 0):

It look's like [horn](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horn) in simplicial sets / [cubical sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cubical+set) (some explanations [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cubical+set+-+exposition)). (**N.B.** It is not about graphs exactly. It is much wider and uses constructions of the nature **@user340082710** asks about.)

Some recent works with them seem to be tightly connected with contemporary well-computated foundations of mathematics ([homotopy type theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), cubical type theory). Look these [references and notes](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt#references-and-notes) to obtain more information.